# It is possible to set up inverse/forward search in LyX with zathura pdf viewer?

Tags: lyx, forward-inverse-search

In the following wiki page of LyX it is explained how to set up reverse search in LyX using Okular and PDF Sumatra:
http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/SyncTeX#toc1

Additionally, the following link gives the set up using [zathura](https://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) and gvim:
https://wiki.math.cmu.edu/iki/wiki/tips/20140310-zathura-fsearch.html

Nevertheless, I could not combine the information of these two links to set up reverse search using LyX and zathura. It is possible to realize this set up?